# using two fadeToggle on one site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the `fadeToggle` on two separated divs on the same site but only one works. I can deactivate one and then the other one runs but not both at the same time. 
So if the user clicks on `comment-reply-btn` the comment input field should show up and if he clicks on `show-subcom-btn` the comments should show up. 
I have this in the header:

```
$(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle().delay(1000);
 })

$(".show-subcom-btn").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next(".show-subcom").fadeToggle().delay(1000);
 })
```

and here are the two divs which I would like to show for each click.

```
<div class="show-subcom hhh2" style="display: none;" >
  {% for child_comment in comment.children %}
  <blockquote>
  <img src="{{ child_comment.user.usersettings.profileimage.url }}" class="childcommentpic">
<a href="/profiles/{{child_comment.user}}">{{child_comment.user}}</a> <span>{{child_comment.timestamp}}</span><br>
  <span>{{child_comment.content }}</span>

  </blockquote>
  {%endfor%}
  </div>

  <div class="comment-reply" style="display: none;">
  <form method="POST" action=".">{%csrf_token%}
    {{comment_form|crispy}}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ comment.id }}" name="parent_id">
    <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-default" name="">
  </form>
</div>
```

if it does not work with FadeToggle what else would you recommend to accomplish this effect?
I did not find anything here or on google. the only stuff that I found was like "show both at FadeToogles at ones" or "show one when the other one is hiding" etc. so if this question is already answered please send me the link. Thanks in advise

Comment: Where are your buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If both buttons is placed top of "show-subcom" class then it is issue with dom element selection.

```
$(this).parent().next(".show-subcom").fadeToggle().delay(1000);
```

you need to trick above line, My guess is

```
$(this).parent().next().next(".show-subcom").fadeToggle().delay(1000);
```

My Personal opinion goes with do not parent/next instead of add id to parent and that target of that id while selecting element
Example :

```
$("#commentsection > .show-subcom").fadeToggle().delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load staticfiles %} // This is for static files
    <div>
      <p class="loag">Comments</p>
      <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ comment_form|crispy }}
          <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-primary">
      </form>
      <hr>

    {% for comment in comments %}
    <blockquote>
        <div class="media">
          <img class="mr-3" src="{% static 'img/comment-icon.svg' %}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="mt-0">{{ comment.user}}</h4>
              <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
              <footer>
                  <small class="text-muted">Posted {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago
                      {% if comment.children.count > 0 %}
                          {{ comment.children.count }} Comment{% if comment.children.count > 1 %}s{% endif %} |
                      {% endif %}

                      <!-- <a class='comment-reply-btn' href=''>Reply</a> -->
                  </small>
              </footer>
                <!-- For child Comment/reply -->
              <blockquote>
            <a class='comment-reply-btn' href='' style='font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; color: #3333ff;'>Reply</a>
                <div class="comment-reply" style="display: none">
                    {% for child_comment in comment.children %}
                        <div class="media mt-3">
                            <a class="pr-3" href="#">
                                <img src="{% static 'img/comment-icon.svg' %}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="mt-0">{{ child_comment.user}}</h4>
                                <p>{{ child_comment.content }}</p>
                                <footer>
                                    <small class="text-muted">Posted {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    {% endfor %}

                     <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                         {{ comment_form|crispy }}
                         <!-- <textarea name="content" id="id_content" required="" rows="5" cols="10" class="textarea form-control form-control form-control"></textarea> -->
                         <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                         <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-primary">
                     </form>
                 <!-- End For child Comment/reply -->
              </div><!-- comment-reply -->
              </blockquote>
             <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </blockquote>

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Add some description, it would help much than just  piece of code.

Comment: $(this).next('.comment-reply').slideToggle();

Comment: <a class='comment-reply-btn' href=''>Reply</a>     ---- use this code out of the parent blockquote and use the jquery code into your base.html or base.js whather you put all of your jquery code. $(this).next('.comment-reply').slideToggle()